# Copying sheet to another workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy one sheet to another workbook using VBA. However I receive an Application defined or object defined error, when it comes to the copy row.

```
Dim x As Workbook   

  Set x = Workbooks.Open("S:\INM\MME9EG\Zahlenwerk MMA2EG Equities\DHN\DHN_Europa.xls")

  x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV150000").Copy _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1:IV150000").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: `x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV150000").Copy _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1:IV150000")` though the two are not the same size.

Comment: `x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV150000").Copy _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1")` no need to specify output size with Copy

Comment: still not working

Comment: @tombata : Could you close that question too please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not to bother about matching source and destination ranges sizes

```
With x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV150000")
    .Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value
End With
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But nobody seems to care about this solution...so it's harmless

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with your formulation :

```
x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV150000").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1:IV150000").PasteSpecial
```

You are specifying a `Destination` for the `Copy` method by using `_` and yet you use `PasteSpecial` so it isn't a Range anymore, thus the error!

Also, you are opening an `.xls` file, which is the *old* Excel format and only contains 65,536 rows and you are trying to copy 150,000!

See : https://superuser.com/a/366473/505550

---

A lot of ways to do this :

If you specify the output size, you'll have to be accurate so that input and output size are the same :

```
x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV65536").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1:IU65533").PasteSpecial
```

or

```
x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV65536").Copy _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1:IU65533")
```

Or you could just specify the 1st cells in which you want to paste :

```
x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV65536").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1:IU65533").PasteSpecial
```

or

```
x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV65536").Copy _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1")
```

Or the best way for the end :
you'll have to be accurate but it is much much faster for transfering data (and data only!)):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1:IU65533").Value = _
x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV65536").Value
```